# Python Post Request Format?

Tags: python, api

I'm trying perform a POST request with a JSON payload in Python but nothing happens when I run my script:

I have my payload:

```
newTicket = {
    "subject": "Testing POST API request", 
    "person": 749, 
    "department": 1, 
    "X-DeskPRO-API-Key": "API KEY",
    "Authorization": "API KEY"
}
```

and my POST request (URL and API keys removed):

```
postResponse = requests.post("url.com", json = newTicket,    
    headers={
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "X-DeskPRO-API-Key": "API KEY",
        "Authorization": "API KEY"
    }
)
```

Nothing happens when I check my software, is my json payload formatted properly? What am I doing wrong here?

When I print the response with:

```
print(postResponse.status_code)
```

I get:

```
200
```

And when I check my software's API call log, nothing relating to my POST request is there.

When I check the request body with:

```
print(postResponse.request.body)
```

I get:

None

Answer (score 0):

Status 200 means the request worked and returned no error. Check the response like this

```py
print(postResponse.json())
```

Comment: When I do this, for some reason I get a JSON object that's similar to what I would get if I performed a "GET request" instead of a POST

Comment: POST request can return data in JSON format just as with GET requests. It all depends how the POST request is defined in the API you use. However, I don't think I can help you any further with your issue considering you are getting status code 200. You could double check how to pass the data in your post request.